# Array empty after a push operation inside Mongoose findbyId operation

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to insert objects to a array after a Mongoose FindById operation.It is showing empty after the for loop execution.Please help.I have attached a snippet below.Thanks

```
var list=[]
for( var i=0;i<groupdata.length;i++){
   Group.findById(groupdata[i],function(err,group){
   if(err){
   return callback(err,null)
   }
 for(var j=0;j<group.members.length;j++){
 list.push(group.members)
 }
 });
 }
console.log(list)---->showing empty array
```

Comment: `findById` is asynchronous so `console.log` is called before any of the `findById` callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to test without more info but you may just need to change it to:

```
var list=[]
for( var i=0; i < groupdata.length; i++){
  Group.findById(groupdata[i],function(err,group){
    if(err){
      return callback(err,null)
    }
   for(var j=0;j<group.members.length;j++){
     list.push(group.members[j])
   }
  });
}
console.log(list)
```

The only difference is in the `list.push(group.members)` line.  I added `[j]`.  It's also very possible that you could simplify your code using `$in` and the underscore.js library:

```
Group.find({_id: {$in: groupdata}}).
exec(function(err, groups) {
  //check out underscore.js's pluck for a quick way to do what you're after
  var list = _.flatten(_.pluck(groups, 'members'));
});
```